# ssrs change background color of line chart

Tags: reporting-services, report, expression

I'm developing a report in which I have to highlight a particular period on a line chart.
To be more precise if the dates in the x axis are more than a given date the chart background colour after that date will have to be light green otherwise white.
Here is the expression

```
=IIF(Fields!Week_Day_Of.Value>Fields!startdate.Value,"LightGreen","#00000000")
```

I have put the expression in the chart area properties (Fill).
Fields!Week_Day_Of.Value represents the values on the X axis.
Fields!startdate.Value represents the parameter beyond which the cart has to turn light green.
It's not doing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you cannot fill parts of the chart background like this.  Your best bet is to add another column data series on the secondary vertical axis that has a value of 1 or 0 depending on the expression you have above and set the colour of the series to whatever you need.  To get the columns wide enough to form a solid block of colour, you will need to set the `CustomAttributes -> MinPixelPointWidth` property to `100`.

You can then set the secondary axis to hidden by right clicking on the chart area and unchecking `Show Secondary Vertical Axis` and check the `Do not show this series in a legend` option in the `Legend` area of the series properties.

Do all this and your chart will look something like this:
[image]